# Graphviz/Customizing the edge alignment

Tags: graphviz

*Sample code:*

```
graph g{

rankdir = "LR";
splines=false; 

"tab1" [
label = <<table border="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="deepskyblue">
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="gray">header</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f1" border="1" width="20" bgcolor="deepskyblue">row1</td></tr>  
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f2" border="1" bgcolor="gold">row2</td></tr>
</table>>
shape = "yes"
width ="2"
group="udm";
//pos="-10,-10!"
];

tab1:f1 -- tab1:f2 [color=blue,style=solid penwidth=1.5,constraint=true];

}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRqkV.png)

While keeping rankdir="LR", I would like to draw a picture as below -

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntthS.png)

Would you please advise how this target can be achieved?

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

To flip the edge to the right side (east side) add a **port** designation (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/)  (see below)

Also fixed one (unimportant) item:

- **shape** of "yes" is invalid (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)

So:

```
graph g{

rankdir = "LR";
splines=false; 

"tab1" [
label = <<table border="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="deepskyblue">
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="gray">header</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f1" border="1" width="20" bgcolor="deepskyblue">row1</td></tr>  
    <tr><td colspan="75" port="f2" border="1" bgcolor="gold">row2</td></tr>
</table>>
//shape = "yes"  // no shape value of "yes"
shape = "box" 
width ="2"
//group="udm";   // not needed
//pos="-10,-10!"
];

// use the "east" (e) ports for head and tail
tab1:f1:e -- tab1:f2:e [color=blue,style=solid penwidth=1.5,constraint=true];
}
```

Gives:
[image]